# Swift 3.0 convert Data to Array<UInt8>

Tags: ios, swift3, uint8array

How to convert Data to array of UInt8?

```
func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data) {
print("recieved:\(data)")
let arr: [UInt8] = Data(???)???
}
```

log
recieved:70 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
var recived = [UInt8]()

func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data) {
        recived.removeAll()
        print("recieved:\(data))")
        recived.append(contentsOf: data)
}
```

Answer (score 23):

In Swift 3, `Data` works as a `Collection` of `UInt8`, so you can simply use `Array.init`.

```
var received: [UInt8] = []

func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data) {
    print("received:\(data))")
    received = Array(data)
}
```

---

But, `Array.init` (or `Array.append(contentsOf:)`) copies the content of the `Data`, so it's not efficient when you need to work with huge size of `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [withUnsafeBytes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes):

```
let data = "ABCD".data(using: .ascii)!
data.withUnsafeBytes {  (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    //Prints 67 which is the ASCII value of 'C'
    print(pointer[2])
}
```